# Why is this JSX returning only the last thing I added to the object?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a function that is used to build a search filter, and in that function I have this

```
    const filter = {
      $and: [
        req.query.category !== "" ? { category: req.query.category } : {},
        req.query.subCategory !== "" ? { tags: req.query.subCategory } : {},
        req.query.contentType !== ""
          ? {
              contentType: req.query.contentType,
            }
          : {},
        req.query.searchTerm !== ""
          ? ({
              name: {
                $regex: "(?i)" + req.query.searchTerm + "(?-i)",
                $options: "i",
              },
            },
            {
              tags: {
                $regex: "(?i)" + req.query.searchTerm + "(?-i)",
                $options: "i",
              },
            },
            {
              description: {
                $regex: "(?i)" + req.query.searchTerm + "(?-i)",
                $options: "i",
              },
            })
          : {},
      ],
    };
```

But when I print `console.log(filter)`, all I get is this `{ '$and': [ {}, {}, {}, { description: [Object] } ] }`. But lets say I remove description or even put tags after description like this

```
 {
              description: {
                $regex: "(?i)" + req.query.searchTerm + "(?-i)",
                $options: "i",
              },
            },
            {
              tags: {
                $regex: "(?i)" + req.query.searchTerm + "(?-i)",
                $options: "i",
              },
            }
```

, then all I get is this `{ '$and': [ {}, {}, {}, { tags: [Object] } ] }`.

Why is the array of objects empty other than the very last one every time?

Comment: what is `req.query` ?

Comment: its my search term, so if i print the value of that, the value is correct. so for testing purposes it could be any string.

Comment: yeh but the reason you are getting `{}` is because: `req.query.subCategory === ""` so it's an empty string. if it is not an empty string it will return you that: `{ tags: req.query.subCategory } `

Comment: it looks like `req.query.searchTerm` is not `""`, also the parentheses around the name, tags, and description objects should probably be brackets or one object all together

Comment: I don't see any JSX in this question?

Comment: I think you mean `req.query.searchTerm` right? The code says if serachTerm is not empty, then make searchTerm hold the objects name, description, and tags. At least thats what it should be doing.

Comment: only for the last one is it referencing `searchTerm` and according to the question, that one is behaving correctly

Comment: I thought the same about the parentheses but if i replace with brackets, it doesn't work

Comment: @BrianThompson yeah this is not related to React or JSX, should be just JavaScript and JSON

Answer (score 1):

Try splitting up the objects for `req.query.searchTerm` like so:

```
const filter = {
  $and: [
    req.query.category !== "" ? { category: req.query.category } : {},
    req.query.subCategory !== "" ? { tags: req.query.subCategory } : {},
    req.query.contentType !== ""
      ? {
          contentType: req.query.contentType,
        }
      : {},
    req.query.searchTerm !== ""
      ? {
          name: {
            $regex: "(?i)" + req.query.searchTerm + "(?-i)",
            $options: "i",
          },
        } : {},
    req.query.searchTerm !== ""
      ? {
          tags: {
            $regex: "(?i)" + req.query.searchTerm + "(?-i)",
            $options: "i",
          },
        } : {},
    req.query.searchTerm !== ""
      ? {
          description: {
            $regex: "(?i)" + req.query.searchTerm + "(?-i)",
            $options: "i",
          },
        } : {},
  ],
};
```

This will however give you 6 objects in the `$and` list

Comment: That gave me the desired object,  but for some reason the API isnt searching correctly. I am using MongoDB atlas and using this object to search in the DB.

Comment: Chris's Answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62521413/7508418 is closer to your original formatting, I would only recommend removing the parentheses. Edit: I actually see what you're trying to do now, let me change my answer.

Comment: I am getting a `property assignment expected` error when I use Chris's answer. I am using Mongoose Pagination, idk if that helps at all, but thats my end goal is to use this object as a filter in mongooses Pagination() method. Like this ` await Content.paginate(filter, options, (err, result)...`

Comment: Take a look at my updated answer and see if that formatting helps you

Comment: Still not working, I am getting the correct object `filter` or so I think, but for some reason your updated code only allows it to search by name and it ignored tags and description. I am at a loss. I don't see any example of pagination being used the way I am either

Comment: I'm not incredibly versed in Mongo, I would recommend making a new question specifically tagged for mongodb and mongoose-pagination, whatever those may be. Also, looking at the documentation, you might want to do away with the ternary operators and look at list.append() for JavaScript

Comment: maybe you know why this isn't allowed?
 ``` $and: [
        { name: { `${req.query.searchTerm}` },
      ],
    };```
is this not how to use js variables in JSON?

Comment: yes you can do that as long as you're using backticks: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 1):

You need to figure out what your return object should look like.

Your code currently looks something like this:

```
if (searchTerm !== '') {
   return( { a: 'a' } , { b: 'b' } , { c: 'c' } ); // returns { c: 'c' }
}
```

It sounds like you might want to return something more like this:

```
if (searchTerm !== '') {
   return( { a: 'a' , b: 'b' , c: 'c' } ); // returns 1 object with all 3 properties
           ^                          ^
}
```

```js
        req.query.searchTerm !== ""
          ? ({ // added a {
            //{ // remove various other braces ({ })
              name: {
                $regex: "(?i)" + req.query.searchTerm + "(?-i)",
                $options: "i",
              },
            //},
            //{
              tags: {
                $regex: "(?i)" + req.query.searchTerm + "(?-i)",
                $options: "i",
              },
            //},
            //{
              description: {
                $regex: "(?i)" + req.query.searchTerm + "(?-i)",
                $options: "i",
              },
            //}
          }) // added a }
          : {},
```

Comment: This is giving me a syntax error if I replace my code with this